# Avoid Nested RxSwift Subscriptions

Tags: ios, nested, subscription, rx-swift

I have to work with 2 database objects which are related to each other. The way I have done it created nested subscriptions. I read a couple of blogs but couldn't find a way to do away with nested subscriptions. Any pointers would be appreciated.

A topic has a list of children. After retrieving all the children, I need to print "topic name" + "child name", after iterating over all the children. This is a simplified version of the problem statement. The only catch is data service returns observable of database objects to which I need to subscribe.

```
let ds = DatabaseService()    

func createBindings() {
    _ = ds.getTopics()
        .flatMapLatest{self.updateSections(array: $0)}
        .subscribe()
}

func updateSections(array: [Topics]) -> Observable<Void> {
    for topic in array {
        let children = topic.children
        for id in children {
            _ = ds.getChildWith(id: id).map { lo in
                //do business related stuff
                }
                .subscribe()
        }
    }
    return .never()
}
```

I want to avoid another subscription in flatMapLatest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and combine streams created by `getChildWith(id: id)` with [combineLatest](http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest) operator. (All this streams will need to complete in order to complete the returning stream).

---

It should look something like:

```
let ds = DatabaseService()

func createBindings() {
    _ = ds.getTopics()
        .flatMapLatest{self.updateSections(array: $0)}
        .subscribe()
}

func updateSections(array: [Topics]) -> Observable<Void> {
    let allStreams = array.flatMap { topic in
        topic.children.map { id in
            return ds.getChildWith(id: id).map { lo in
                //do business related stuff
            }
        }
    }

    return Observable.combineLatest(allStreams, { _ in () })
}
```

---

P.S. Try to avoid ignoring `Disposable` you'll end up never releasing that stream.