# Rxswift: Avoid nested subscirption

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have an Observable array of objects to subscribe to, each object has to be bind with a UI component and inside UI component I have to add tap gesture on a subview which requires another subscription. I am new to RxSwift and did a bit reading on similar questions and articles but either I couldnt understand or content is not much related.

```
   items.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] items in
        for item in items {
            let view = aView()
            view.label.text = item.name
            view.image.rx.touchUpInside.subscribe(onNext: { [viewModel] _ in
                doSomething()
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
           self?.stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
       }
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I have read about `flatMap` [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxswift-deep-inside-flatmap-1ca150c41b18) and a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917935/avoid-nested-rxswift-subscriptions) but couldnt comprehend it. Please explain your answer a bit so I could learn to tackle similar queries.

Comment: What problems do you have with the current code? Where did you got stuck?

Comment: Thanks for comment @Cristik. I want to get rid of nested subscription since it is discouraged.

Comment: Where are `viewModel` and the `disposeBag` inside the closure defined?

Comment: Also, what are you doing with the view instance you create in the for-each statement? Assuming `aView()` returns a new view. Because due to how the code looks right now, you are adding new sets of views to the stack view every time new values are emitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track in that `flatMap` is what you want. What likely is confusing you is that you want to subscribe to lots of Observables (in your for loop) rather than just one. So let's break that down first.

For each item in your array you want to create a view, name it, add it to your stackView and then listen to the `touchUpInside` observable. So make a function just for that (this is essentially taking the body of your for loop and turning it into a free function.):

```
func addView(to stackView: UIStackView, for item: Item) -> Observable<Void> {
    let view = aView()
    view.label.text = item.name
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
    return view.image.rx.touchUpInside
}
```

Note that the above is a *free function*. Do not make it a method in your class; it doesn't require self.

After this refactoring, your original code looks like this:

```
items.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] items in
    for item in items {
        addView(to: self!.stackView, for: item)
            .subscribe(onNext: { [viewModel = self!.viewModel] _ in
                doSomething()
            })
            .disposed(by: self!.disposeBag)
    }
})
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Next we see that you are doing the same thing with every item in the array, and all of their subscriptions will cause the same `doSomething()` to be called... So let's map the array and merge the Observables...

```
func addViewToStack(from item: Item) -> Observable<Void> {
    addView(to: stackView, for: item)
}

items.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] items in
    Observable.merge(items.map { addViewToStack(from: $0) })
        .subscribe(onNext: { [viewModel = self!.viewModel] _ in
            doSomething()
        })
        .disposed(by: self!.disposeBag)
})
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Note, embed the `addViewToStack(from:)` function inside your current function; do not make it a method. That way it will capture the `stackView` without capturing self.

From here... We see that `Observable.merge(items.map(addViewToStack(from:)))` requires an array of items and returns a single Observable, which is exactly what `flatMap`'s signature requires...

```
items
    .flatMap { Observable.merge($0.map { addViewToStack(from: $0) }) }
    .subscribe(onNext: { [viewModel] _ in
        doSomething()
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Now we don't have the inner-subscribe and we also no longer need to capture self.

---

All together, the result looks something like this:

```
class Example {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    func example(items: Observable<[Item]>) {
        func addViewToStack(from item: Item) -> Observable<Void> {
            addView(to: stackView, for: item)
        }

        items
            .flatMap { Observable.merge($0.map { addViewToStack(from: $0) }) }
            .subscribe(onNext: { [viewModel] _ in
                doSomething()
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}

func addView(to stackView: UIStackView, for item: Item) -> Observable<Void> {
    let view = aView()
    view.label.text = item.name
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
    return view.image.rx.touchUpInside
}
```